# Is there any way to run a javascript function by a timer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have an app that gets data from a web service. I want to know that whether there is any way while the app is open but not being used to run a function every few minutes.

Basically, I want to check internet connectivity and check to make sure my web service is up.

Comment: You might want to look at `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function() {
  alert("Will run every 5 seconds");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Will only run once after 5 seconds");
}, 5000);
```

### Edit

As taxicala mentioned in the comments, the function will not be executed UNTIL 5 seconds has passed. If the thread is busy, it might be considerably longer than that. Most of the time it is a non-issue though, but worth having in mind.

Comment: You should add to your answer that the 5 seconds (as per your examples) are not really 5 seconds, if the thread is busy at the time the 5 seconds pass, it won't execute the callback until the thread is free. Those 5 seconds should be taken as an estimate. Most of the times it will be 5 seconds, but in applications that are fully JS based, and do heavy processing, sometimes 5 seconds are not really 5 seconds. Anyhow I will give an upvote as this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInterval or use setTimeout.

setInterval works like a constant loop, so you can get a time for 3 seconds and every second it would run the code inside of the setInterval like so

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
   alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

setTimeout works after a specific amount of time has gone by and then runs some code like so

```
setTimeout(function()
{ 
    alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

The timer is in milliseconds so 1000 = 1 second

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `setInterval` function like:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ yourKeepAliveFunction() }, 1000);
```

In the example above, yourKeepAliveFunction will run every second (1000 ms); myVar holds a handle to the timer, so once you want to stop running it, you can do so like:

```
clearInterval(myVar);
```